# How do I stop Galaxy Store from updating?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-j7

I use Google Play store, and I find it great but I don't really need the auto update feature on my mobile. My mobile has little disk space, so I did the natural thing, uninstalling the updates for various apps, turning off the auto update feature, (via auto update apps-> never).

But then I realised the Galaxy Store app itself can auto update whenever it wants, resetting my device settings, updating a massive bulk of unwanted updates to absolutely useless yet non deletable apps.

How can I keep Galaxy Store from updating?

Comment: Welcome to the world of Samsung :( In South Korea the home land of Samsung they even made a law that bloatware apps on a new device have to be deletable/uninstallable. You can imagine how bad it must have been there for the necessity of making a law...

Comment: I have what I believe is the latest Galaxy Store, v4.5.45.6 (don't quote me), and it allows setting some of its own to negate its power (some). You can remove all its permissions; you can disable its ability to set system settings; you can take away its overlay ability. You can Force Stop, but not disable or uninstall it, so while you can't kill it, you can remove many of its powers and weaken it.

Comment: @wbogacz i have removed all permissions, force stopped about 20 times, yet this app keeps reinstalling... i just can't seem to stop it

Comment: I'm getting more and more glad I never register a Samsung Account to any of my devices. I wonder if auto update is part of the User Rights statement that is agreed to.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the app entirely (via *Settings › Apps*  in the Android settings), or even uninstalling it via ADB (`adb uninstall --user=0 <packageName>`)?

Comment: Warning, before disabling or uninstalling the package make sure to back up  your precious data. Who knows what kind of nonsense app/service dependency Samsung has created on this app store? You might end up in a boot loop. This can happen on a Xiaomi device at least (tried two years ago).